# Island Dimension in Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I am using MS Analysis services.
I the project I have a dimension "Employee".
This dimension originally had only one attribute - "Employee_NAME".
I had to add another attribute - Employee_NR.

Problem is - it can happen that one employee has 2 different Employee_NR.
Because of this, I am getting errors during cube processing.

Additionally "Employee_NAME" is defined as key.

**What I tried so far**:
I added a new attribute "Emp_ID" and my plan was to make this attribute key attribute. But when I tried to save the changes I go the error that say something like the corresponding attribute in cube is defined as WCHAR, and the key column in dimension as INTEGER (as I mentioned, I tried using EMP_ID as key column).
Then I wanted to check how the dimension connects to cube/fact tables. I tried by opening both the cube and the data source view. In both cases, the table/view which the Employee dimension is using is not connected to any other tables - it's an 'island' table. (I did tried by right clicking on the table and selecting the option 'Show Related Tables', and no connected table showed).

I would appreciate an elegant advice about solving this problem.

**UPDATE**:
Afer following instructions from Jo Douglass, I got the following error message when I tried to save  the changes (I am translating from German, so the translation may differ a little from the exact error message):

> Dimension Employee cannot be saved because of the following errors:
>   Error in Metadata-Manager. The Element Property ID 'Emp ID 1' in Employee-Attribute is not corresponding to any available attribute in the dimension.

Comment: Have you added Emp_ID to any of the other tables which you need to have linked to Employee? If they were linking on Employee_NAME before, and you've now defined Emp_ID as the key, they should link on that. Note that it's best practice to *always* use an ID like the one you've made for Employee as the key (this concept is called a surrogate key) for precisely this reason, so you might want to make the same change to other tables to prevent trouble later on.

Comment: As far as the cube issues, you'll need to edit the cube dimension, right click on Employee_NAME, and do Set Attribute Usage > Regular. Then you can add the new Emp_ID as an attribute, and use the same method to set that as a key (right click, Set Attribute Usage > Key). Once you've gotten back to me on the above question, I'll chuck all of this into a proper answer if it's on the right track.

Comment: I didn't get what exactly the problem is. 
@Adam - Could you please emphasize more on the question? If it is about one Employee having multi-valued attribute `Employee_NR` then it becomes a database design issue. [More details here](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/dimensions-with-multi-valued-attributes/).

Comment: @JoDouglass: I updated my answer, after trying your instructions. Please send me your feedback.

Comment: Without looking at it it's difficult to guess exactly what might be going on, but a fairly general suggestion which has saved me before: sometimes it can be helpful to simply remove an attribute from a cube dimension, then re-add it. @AkshayRane is correct that you may want to take a step back and consider your overall database design, though - you're likely to keep running into problems like this and you'll save time in the long run by getting the database schema right before you try to push it through into the cube.

Comment: Well, the translation got me kind of confused.The error you get is on the similar lines what has been described [here](https://sqljoe.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/ssas-errors-in-the-metadata-manager-the-dimension-with-id-of-xxx-referenced-by-the-xxx-cube-does-not-exist/) and [here](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-faq/29-mgmt/154-how-fix-errors-in-the-metadata-manager-the-attribute-with-id-of-name-of-referenced). Basically, your MOLAP data is corrupted and you need to redo your deployment afresh.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Surrogate Key column to this dimension, then use that as the "Key".  Name and NR would become just Attributes, which can then happily have one-to-one or one-to-many relationships with the Key.

This change implies you will need lookup logic for your Measure Group / Fact data, to determine the correct Surrogate Key value to associate each Fact row to.

In summary - Welcome to the world of Dimensional Modelling!  I recommend the Kimball Group as thought leaders in this space - they have a wealth of articles, courses and books available from their site: http://www.kimballgroup.com